# Google Compute Engine - Can't reach external IP of instance

Tags: networking, debian, google-compute-engine, firewall

I'm running a Node app on a HTTP instance with Debian-8 and only can reach my app via port 8080 which my node server is running on.  If I remove the port and try to access through port 80, then I get a refused to connect error.

I've allowed tcp:80 to all targets in Networking -> Firewall Rules and also verified that my iptables are open in Debian. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - My port forwarding was not set property in Debian.